# Multiprocess not found with Pathos

Tags: python, pool, multiprocess, pathos

This is the first time I am using `pathos` library in python under Visual Studio 2019 on windows 10. When the debugger encounters the line

`solver.SetMapper(Pool(self.Config.NumberOfProcessors).map)`

I get error

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiprocess'`

I have the following statement at the beginning of my code

`from pathos.pools import ProcessPool as Pool`

I have C++ compilers(multiple version of Visual studios) and I have used latest version of `pip` to install the packages. I also see that the `multiprocess` package has been installed under `pathos`.

I do see multiple question on the same topic on the web, but unable to resolve the issue

Actually I can reproduce the same situation with a simple example like:

`def foo(x):
        return x
    def bar(x):
        return foo(x)
    x=Pool(4).map(bar, [0, 1])
    print (x)`

Comment: Please provide a minimal bit of code that reproduces what you are seeing.  To me, it looks like you are calling something within the constructor of a pool within a method of a mystic solver.  But, it's hard to tell what's going on unless there's code that can be tested.

ModuleNotFoundError is often indicative of the module not being installed, or installed to an different python than the python being used.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Yes this is from a large code that uses mystic to perform optimization. If I turn off the calls to the `pathos` library everything works fine in serial mode. I see I have `pathos` and `mystic` in same python environment (Python 3.7 (64 bit), pathos-0.2.5, multiprocess- 0.70.9 and mystic 0.3.5).

Comment: @MikeMcKerns, I can recreate the issue with a simple call as shown in the question

Answer (score 0):

A new installation of python 3.8.1 seems to make this issue go away

Comment: I've checked on python 3.x (x=6,7,8), and for multiprocess-0.79.10.dev0, pathos-0.2.6.dev0, and dill-0.3.2-dev0.  I'm not seeing this error either.

Comment: Not sure, what could have been the exact reason. All I know, my first attempt was to use the python that came with visual studio. I was using visual studio to pick the environment. When I installed 3.8.1, I installed it on my own, and told the installer to add python to the path. Then I used the visual studio to point to the new installation